# SymbolSet Issues in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, webfonts, icon-fonts

I have been using Symbolset fonts (Standard and Social) for a few months now and love them. Recently I have been noticing some issues in IE8 though. Some sites I am doing are not loading at all in IE8. It has this in the bottom social bar: http://cl.ly/image/3y1o2R2X2L1t, which makes me think it has to do with the Symbolset files. I can't for the life of me figure out what the issue is though. Any ideas what might be causing the issue or something I may be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the font format you're trying to feed to IE 8 is not supported.

TTF/OTF, for example, is partially supported in IE 9 and 10 but not supported in IE 8.

http://caniuse.com/ttf

Answer (score 0):

I would check the compatibility table on this page. http://blog.symbolset.com/browser-support

For IE8 I have used the unicode option to get the desired result.

Example

```
<i class="ss-icon ss-social">&#xF611;</i>
```